# Setting background custom color, XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, apache

I use this code to change the font in excel to color, which I define

```
        Color sColor = new Color (value,0,0);
        XSSFColor userColor = new XSSFColor(sColor);

        CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();

        font.setColor(userColor);
        style.setFont(font);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Can I change the cell's Background same way.

I saw the question here
 [Setting background custom color not working for XSSF in Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861987/setting-background-custom-color-not-working-for-xssf-in-apache-poi)
And I used the code:

```
        XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(value, 0, 0));
        ((XSSFCellStyle)cellStyle).setFillBackgroundColor(color);

        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

The background still always white.

Am sure that all other parts of the code written properly, because it works when I changed the font.

I have office 2010 on my computer

Comment: "but I had error on" what error? compiler error? runtime error? what is the error/what is it supposed to be doing that its not?

Comment: @scigs can you please see the question after editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all
I found solution now

```
        XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();

        XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(value, 0, 0));

        ((XSSFCellStyle)cellStyle).setFillBackgroundColor(color);
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color); 
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Comment: Does not work in modern POI 4.1.2, unfortunately. We can't set `XSSFColor` to `setFillForegroundColor` anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Create cell style object:

```
CellStyle backgroundStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
```

Set custom color:

```
backgroundStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
```

Add style to the cell:

```
cell.setCellStyle(backgroundStyle);
```